# If I install a package with pip in a Python 3 environment is that package guaranteed to be Python 3 compatible?

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I have a Python 3 environment, everything is working correctly and as expected, i.e.:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.6.8

$ pip --version
pip 18.1 from /Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

I am porting a Python 2 project to Python 3. I have the requirements.txt file from my Python 2 project - if I install these dependences in my Python 3 environment, e.g.

```
$ pip install -r my_python2_requirements.txt
```

And that completes successfully am I guaranteede that all of my dependencies are Python 3 compatible?

Or to put it another way: Is it possible to install a Python 2 only package with Python 3/pip (i.e. a package that will not work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely certain about this, so I ran the following test.

I selected a random module from PyPi which was marked 'Python 2 only' and tried to install it on both versions. For my test I used [patchit](https://pypi.org/project/patchit/).

The `pip` command hit the same URL, and the pip3 call even detected and used the cached `tar.gz` file. So it would seem that `pip` does not offer the protection you wish for. (Of course for packages that support both 2 and 3, it should install the corresponding version)

---

From the [official transition guide](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html):

> Use `caniusepython3` to find out which of your dependencies are blocking your use of Python 3 (`pip install caniusepython3`)

That should help determine things and modify the `requirements.txt` as needed.